# Preventing the rotation of a 2D unstructured grid in VTK

Tags: qt4, vtk

I'm embedding a VTK window in a Qt Application with QVTKRenderWindowInteractor. In this window, I need to display a mesh created as a vtkUnstructuredGrid. 
Because my data is only 2D, I'd like to make sure that the camera always stays along a normal to the data.
What should I do to block the camera ?
Thanks a lot in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short story: use a specific `vtkInteractorStyle`. 
There are a few styles already available (like `vtkInteractorStyleRubberBandZoom`, etc) but at worst, a `vtkInteractorStyle` can be subclassed and tailored to one's needs. 
In this example, we could disable the basic behavior for a left button (camera rotation) and use another behavior instead.